# Como puedo traer todos los registros de multiples colecciones en Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
Region --> localidad 1 
                       --> Ambulancia --> todos los registros
                       --> Policia --> todos los registros
       --> localidad 2
                       --> Ambulancia --> todos los registros
                       --> Policia --> todos los registros
       --> localidad 3
                       --> Ambulancia --> todos los registros
                       --> Policia --> todos los registros
```

Necesito obtener el total de registros DE TODAS LAS LOCALIDADES tanto de las ambulancias por un lado, como de policia tambien.
El objetivo final es hacer una estadistica de todas las localidades contabilizando ambulancia y policia.

Mi problema es que no se como hacerlo de manera optima, no veo logico tener que hacer 2 consultas por cada localidad cuando en todas se llaman igual.

Espero que me puedan orientar. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta [cómo se cobra](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example) el uso de Firestore. No es conveniente leer todos los documentos cada que vas a sacar métricas y estadísticas, eso aumentaría mucho el uso de la base de datos. Como sugerencia, checa [esta guía](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) sobre cómo hacer los cálculos y minimizar el uso de la base.

Por otro lado, tampoco es posible recuperar todas las subcolecciones en una consulta. Puedes usar *[Collection Group queries](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html)* para colecciones que tengan el mismo nombre, pero requerirás más de una al final.